# Android YouTube Player API Showing Error: ERROR_CONNECTING_TO_SERVICE

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am using Youtube player API in my app by extending YouTubeBaseActivity

it running awesome on some devices but on some devices, it showing error

ERROR CONNECTING TO SERVICE

And it starts to work if youtube is running in the background,

How can I connect to that service when it is offline?
Will I need to call that service first or something?

Please help me resolve this problem